# Fast way to determine if variable is a function?

Tags: reflection, lua, metadata

To determine if a variable is a function, I use the following method

```
function isFunction(variable)
    return type(variable) == "function"
end
```

To my knowledge, this is a string comparison. As I've understood it, string comparisons are **relatively slow** and I fear this function might be a bottleneck in my code. Is there a less costly way to determine if a variable is a function?

I'm hoping there's a function which returns an integer that indicates the type of the variable instead. Or I can ask my question another way: How does `type(var)` determine the type of a variable? Surely, each variable can't hold a string representing its type so I'm guessing there is some backend-stuff in lua that looks up the string `"function"` when invoking `type(var)`.

Comment: not sure if you shouldn think about your software design if you have to check variables for being a function so often that it is a significant bottleneck...

Comment: Honestly, not quite the answer I was looking for, but you're right. It got me thinking, and I probably won't need a fast way to check the types anyways. For the sake of the question, how about we pretend I'm asking to check if it's a string instead ;-)

Comment: Aside; "variable" should be "value". Variables don't have types; only values do.Values are produced by expressions, which, of course, could be as simple as a variable.

Answer (score 8):

String comparisons in Lua are really fast because most strings are interned.

Internally, every Lua value contains a tag identifying its type. It is this tag that `type` uses.